# Tourist Schengen Visa Sponsorship Queries?

Tags: schengen, europe, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

I'm new on this forum website. I'm a student, i'm currently 21 years old. I don't have a job obviously because I'm a student. If ever I have, I don't think my salary can handle my travel expenses.

My biological brother and I talked about travelling. He's going to Japan next month and I told him to sponsor me, but since he'll be there next month, that would be too late. Then I raised this issue with him. He wants to travel to Europe after 6 months. He said that if possible, this will be my graduation gift from him. I want to travel to Europe so bad. I just really love it, its history etc.

My brother earns almost 2000 euros per month and I think this will be enough for us (plus his savings). He's been working for a year with that company, which makes him a regular employee and proves his stability in his job. He's not a permanent resident or citizen of any developed or free visa countries , though he works in Saudi Arabia (and he has a very descent job there that's why he has a big monthly salary). We are citizens of a developing country btw (Philippines).

Now, going back to the question, can my brother sponsor my trip to Europe (those countries under Schengen)? I'll be with him while travelling. He will handle all the expenses (our accommodation, ticket, food, etc). Our planned destinations are Germany, France, Denmark, Netherlands, Switzerland, Austria, Italy, Spain, & Finland, if we can make it within a fortnight or month.

If this is possible, can you give me some official website links which talk about this matter? Or Can you just directly answer me here? What will be the process and how long will it take? How difficult? and what is the average percentage to be approved or declined?

Please give us advice on how to convince a European embassy about this matter.
We will be there to go on a tour only, without any intentions to stay permanently or look for a job. We'll be there for a fortnight or a month.

PLEASE GIVE ME HOPE!! THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate questions as part of the visa application:

- **Who pays for the trip and why?** It should be a person who is giving you the money as a gift, with no hope or expectation of repayment. An older brother giving money to a younger sibling is reasonable, if the older brother can afford it. €2000 per month sounds as if he can afford it. So there must be clear documentation what your brother earns and what he normally spends on taxes, housing, food, and other cost of living.
- **Are your conditions in your homeland stable?** A well-paid job is best but it is not necessary. You should document your finances, with income and expenditures, even if those finances are not used to pay for the trip.

And a separate word of advice, don't do nine countries in two weeks. You will spend a lot of time and money on flights or trains, and little time on sightseeing. A reasonable itinerary also helps to make your trip seem credible.

Decide what you want to see most. Paris and the [Louvre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvre)? Austria and the [Alps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_Austria)? Rome and the [Colloseum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_Austria)? Plan on at least one **full** day in that place, better two or three. You won't enjoy the sights if you're already hurrying to the airport. Then consider what you can see nearby. If you visit Rome, perhaps Venice or Florence. If you visit Paris, perhaps the Loire.

Then, if you want to see different parts of Europe, plan for a day to transfer. A leisurely breakfast, then on to the airport or perhaps to the train station, arriving at a new destination in the evening.